# Referencing Page Method in ASP.Net Web Service

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to access a page method from centralized module.

- I tried putting it in a master page it didn't work
- I tried putting it in a web service and did the following

  1. added its path to the script manager that its existed in the master page
  2. added a web service reference to the project
  3. configured the web.config for the page methods

Also didn't work (kept telling me that "PageMethods is not defined" <- JavaScript error)

- tried to access the page methods through http request from Javascript, got server error response (500)

What am I missing?

Comment: The 500 server response indicates that there was a server-side error executing the code of your web services.  Try debugging the web service at the point where it gets the http request.

Comment: i put a break point at the first line of the function but it didn't reach it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed example #2 at this link and it worked fine (the samples appear to be broken however):  http://www.asp.net/Ajax/Documentation/Live/tutorials/ExposingWebServicesToAJAXTutorial.aspx

Here are the steps I took:
1) create a basic .asmx web service with 'HelloWorld' method
2) add the attribute [ScriptService] to the 'HelloWorld' method (and any methods in the web service that you want to call from your page script)
3) add a ScriptManager to the page, referencing the web service, and including InlineScript="true"
4) call the page from Javascript like this:

```
ServiceNamespace.ServiceClass.Method(parameters, callback);
function callback(result)
{
    alert(result);
}
```

The fact that you're getting a 500 error tells me that there's an error in your web service.  I would start here:  can you open your web service URL in a browser successfully, and invoke its methods?

Comment: MY Friend, try to run the example, there is an error that says --Uncaught ReferenceError: Samples is not defined-- neither Samples nor PageMethods is defined and that is what i'm stocked in...
bwt, i did all the steps that are mentioned ...

Comment: Oh wow, sorry for the bad link ... I promise you it used to work great. :)

Comment: I updated my answer to include more detail, since the example is broken.  The example is still accurate however, it's just that the service link is broken so it won't run.

Comment: THANKS ALOT MY FRIEND, but first of all getting the 500 error when using external 3'rd party javascript API to connect to the web server and its not reaching the method (even if the method contained only return "1";), i did all the steps but the "PageMethods" script is not sent with the page --while when using pagemethods in the same page's class it works fine just like the second example that it's working-- ______________________ thanks alot my friend for your time and if could help me with this i will really appreciate it, thanks again,

Comment: First, if you're using a web service, you won't see "PageMethods" in the script-- that's something else (when you're using static methods in your code-behind class).  Second, why are you using 3rd party Javascript?  All you need in order to invoke the web service is a couple of lines of Javascript.  Can you post your actual code?  That might help.

Comment: using the 3'rd party javaScript was only a try to detect the error,
and for the pageMethod i almost tried everything (namespace,classname, websirvice domain , PageMethods .....)
i dont know what i am messing ...

Comment: sir i have a question,
 does the EnablePageMethods=true affect the webservices ?
and if the script manager was in the master page is it wrong or not ?